# Navigation where one set of items is more important

Tags: navigation

I have a webapp where users can create different "events" and manage these events (assign employees, edit date, edit location, etc.). Apart from these event objects a user can also interact with other objects such as employees and his own profile.

The "event" objects however are way more important than all other objects, because Users will mostly interact with these "events". So a navigational structure where the "events" tab is right next to the "employees" or "profile" tab seems not to be right.

Has anybody any useful navigational patterns or design templates when dealing with a similiar kind of problem?

Answer (score 1):

Keep them in separate navigation areas. Group all event-related actions in one toolbar, and give it a prominent position in the design.

Keep secondary actions in a secondary nav area.

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2flzAAk.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>